# Vue - Are there side effects when loading all components async?

Tags: vue.js

I just learned about async components and it reduced my app.js drastically.

However, I wonder what are the side effects if I use it?

For example, I used it everywhere in routes.js (for vue-router) and in components.js (components that are used directly in blade.php). And for dynamic components.

Comment: Sorry for this "noob" question, but I'm not sure...

Comment: lazy loading components are best for component rendering that can be deferred. Components can be tooltips, popovers, modals etc. You only load the component when you need it. Side effect would involve User Experience where deferring a component like a modal takes forever to load under a very slow connection. Best case scenario is to have an error component and a timeout to aid UX